# Clear output value for masked input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I used many packages for react masked input and it looks like that

```
        <InputElement
            mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
            alwaysShowMask={true}
            {...this.props}
            maskChar=" "
        />
```

it works, but when i submit form, mask passed as value instead clean numbers 79999999999.

Comment: Show us your submit method.

Comment: in app few submit methods "<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}" one of them.

Comment: i write that wraper component with hidden field
<code> <MaskedInput
                  value={value}
                  mask="+7(111)-111-11-11"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                  this.setState({outputValue: e.target.value});
                    console.log('outputValue', this.state.outputValue);
                    }}
              />
              <input
                   {...this.props}
                   name={name}
                   value={this.state.outputValue.replace(/\D/g, '')}
                   className="hidden1-element"
             /><code>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`normalize` prop](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/normalizing/) from redux-form and parse the string returned from the input as an integer. Here's how you can do that using a regex and `parseInt`:

```js
normalizePhone(phone) {
  return parseInt(number.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  // `int` is now 73443433443. 
}
```

Then in your redux-form field:

```js
<InputElement
  mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
  alwaysShowMask={true}
  {...this.props}
  maskChar=" "
  normalize={this.normalizePhone}
/>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i use redux-form for handling form and i need prepare data before send. 
Can i edit {...this.props} and add here regexp or maybe in hidden input i can keep clear value?

Comment: Updated my answer, read more about `normalize` [in the documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/normalizing/).